# Owl carousel - auto width, last item is pulled out from stack

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

i am experiencing strange issue with OWL CAROUSEL 2. I'm creating simple carousel for 12 tables, but when using option "autoWidth", last table is pulled out from carousel stack.

**[DEMO](http://goo.gl/uFCU3X)**

If you open fiddle, there is carousel for every month in year. At the end of carousel, there is no December, but if you check source code, you can see that December is there. For some reason OWL carousel plugin is pulling December out.

Any ideas? In advance, many thanks!

Comment: When I reduced the number of items this appeared?

Comment: Do you mean OWL carousel option "items" or number of tables?

Comment: It is working properly with 5 items http://jsfiddle.net/upuak7Lz/11/, but this setting will create blank space (something like empty item) at the end of carousel.

Answer (score 4):

Add just display flex in CSS for `.owl-stage` class and also add jS function for smaller devices.

**CSS**

```
.owl-stage{display:flex}
```

**JS**

```
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({   
   loop: false,   
   autoWidth:true, 
   margin:10,
   nav:true,
   responsive:{
    0:{
     items:1,
     autoWidth:false 
    },
    768:{
     items:3
    }
   } 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue too.
I fixed it in a bad way, but it is working. in both browsers.
The problem was with the `owl-stage` element. The owl carousel lib counted the width property, but the items doesn't fit in the wrapper.
So I have to call a function after the `init` event happened and add about `100px` to it.
I used the setTimeout function with this .Very bad approach I know, but in my project there are a lot of js functions happening and not allways get the right `width` property (sometimes i get `undefined` )

So the code is:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        margin:90,
        nav:true,
        dots:true,
        autoWidth:true,
        afterInit: setWidth()
    });

    function setWidth(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var carWidth = $('.owl-stage').width() + 100;
            $('.owl-stage').width(carWidth);
        },200);

    }
```

I'm sure it could work without `setTimeout`, but deadlines can't wait 
(*feeling bad for it).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this by refreshing the Owl Carousel after being initiated.
Using the following syntax

```
YourCarouselName.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

here's an example of the whole code

```
var YourCarouselName = $('.YourOwlCarouselClassName').owlCarousel({
    margin:5,
    loop:false,
    dots:false,
    nav:false,
    autoWidth:true,
    afterInit: setWidth()
});
function setWidth(){
    setTimeout(()=>{YourCarouselName.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');},1);
}
```

Solution inspired from cs.matyi 's answer on this question